# Intersection points of four lines

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let a be perpendicular to b, and the intersection point on a and b be called "S", further, let c be perpendicular to d and the intersection point be "T", further a $ \nparallel$ c, a $ \nparallel$ d. **Show that these 4 lines have 6 intersection points.**

So I know that n lines can have at most $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$ , so in that case (16-4)/2=6, but how can I argue that this is indeed the case here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of points would reduce from $6$ when one or more pair of lines are coincident or parallel or atleast three lines are concurrent.

Probably one can assume $a,b,c,d$ are distinct to rule out coincidence.

Then $a \nparallel c \,$, $\;a \nparallel d$ can be used to show no two of four lines are parallel.

But this is still not enough since it can happen that one of $c,d$ passes through $S$ i.e.,  for instance if $a,b,c$ concur at $S$ which is distinct from $T$ then there will be less than $6$ intersection points (four in this case, as can be seen by drawing a quick diagram).